# prestashop smarty if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty, prestashop

Consider

```
$price = 100;
$cprice = 50;

if(logged)
{
    if (!$specific_price || $specific_price['cprice'] < 0)
        $price = (float)$result['cprice'];
    else
        $price = (float)$specific_price['cprice'];
}
else
{
    if (!$specific_price || $specific_price['price'] < 0)
        $price = (float)$result['price'];
    else
        $price = (float)$specific_price['price'];
}
```

i have coded this way and the first condition works and the statement executes and for the second condition also the first statements are executing. please help me out guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are receiving?

Comment: no errors only the first if statements works and produces cprice as the results for both the conditions

Comment: This code is in a TPL or PHP file?

Comment: Consider clarifying what the expected values are for each of the 4 conditions or writing a small unit test.

Comment: Can you tell what is logged means what's it's value? and when when it's coming to else then it will output both if and else part? it is correct what i am understanding?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: okay i'll try @AaronBlenkush

Comment: Can you tell what is logged means what's it's value? and when when it's coming to else then it will output both if and else part? it is correct what i am understanding?

Comment: $logged means when the customer is logged in @anantkumarsingh

Comment: you written logged not $logged.

Comment: if the customers is logged in means it should produce $cprice = 50; or it should produce $price = 100; @MarcioSimao

Comment: yeah i tried with that too @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Shouldn't `logged` be `$logged`?

Comment: yes i have tried that too using $logged @MarcioSimao

Comment: can you please put all variable value except logged in you question. It's confusing what are the values of variables used in if else inside outer if and else